# Algorithm for finding matching set for a given set of inputs

Tags: .net, algorithm

I have a set of input sets, each element is consisting of up to 50 chars. Think of a database table with varchar(50) columns, each row being one input set. The column count is usually about within 5-8 range. The number of rows is usually about 2-3 millions but can be up to 150 million. Every column must have a non-null value. Let us call this table T, and each of its rows RT

I have a second set of inputs, which denote a matching pattern.  Just like the original input it can also be considered a database table with the same fixed number of columns (plus metadata for matching target but that part is not relevant). This time however, only one column has to have a value but any of them can be null. Let us call this table M, and each of its rows RM. The typical size of this table is 4000 - 5000 rows But can be up to 40 000.

The task here is for each RT, we have to find the matching RM. Here are the matching rules for a given RT:

1. A match is made if all the elements of RM is the same as the corresponding element in RT. (a string exact match is considered as same). If an element is null in RM, RT is not checked for a match.
2. Only one match is possible. If multiple matches are identified, the one with longest RM  is considered the correct one. The case of multiple RM having same length can be ignored here. We pick just the first one identified.

The code will run on a typical windows client with 4 GB of RAM. So, MT can be held in memory but T cannot.

I am looking for a technique to reduce the number of comparisons. More specifically, are you aware of a technique where the whole MT can be checked against for a given RT. If not, what is the most efficient way to handle this problem?

This is going to be coded in .NET and any existing code or library for .NET is very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Kemal

NOTES:

1. This is not a homework. I graduated about 20 years ago :)
2. There is a variant of this problem with regular expression RMs. But for the current release, a match with simple string equivalence is sufficient.
3. Here is some examples:

RT = { A, B, C, D, E }

RM1 = { A,,,, }
RM2 = { A, B,,, }
RM3 = {A,,,D, E}

For this RT, all of these match. But due to the rule 2, we pick RM3 as the match. Hope this example clarifies

1. the T data is actually not held in a db. It is in many formats including excel, text, xml, and some statistical SW native data files. We have a data-pipe structure that reads data from their native formats on the fly and keeps a cursor. RT is part of that cursor and is simply an array of strings

Comment: This sounds like a homework exercise, so: *what have you tried so far*? [SO] will help with questions but we much prefer if you try and ask for help to progress.

Comment: We need complete matching rules that items in M are following. Are RM's regular expressions, or something else?

Comment: I think you should give some examples of RM and RT and how they match

Comment: Just to clarify: you don't have a DB with the data, and mentioning tables was just for the sake of explanation, right?

Comment: Good question by @ChristianSeverin: What is your actual data structure?

Comment: @Christian: yep, the data is not in a db. It is actually in many formats including excel, text, xml, and some statistical SW native data files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution should involve some kind of matching tree. The objective is to traverse the tree for each RT until you reach a leaf node, at which point you have maybe several matches but one of them is the best one. Nodes in the tree are matches (maybe partial matches, like `{A,,,D,}`) and algorithm falls to one branch or the other if node-match is satisfied or not.

There is more than one way implement this, and to pick one you need first to decide how fast is fast enough for you. One thing to take into consideration is spatial locality, because for a large non-optimized tree algorithm will be jumping around the memory like a raving rabbit, and completely disregard benefits of memory cache.

Let's assume that binary tree is good enough. Algorithm follows left branch if match is satisfied, and right branch otherwise. So, for your case root node is match `{A,,,,}`, and the complete tree is as follows (each node tries to match something, and has a branch `y>` if match is found and branch `n>` if there is no match:

```
{A,,,,}
 y> {,B,,,}
  y> out, matching {A,B,,,}
  n> {,,,D,E}
   y> out, matching {A,,,D,E}
   n> out, matching {A,,,,}
 n> out, no match
```

Compiling this matching tree from M table is a problem on itself. You should consider the statistical occurrence of items in T table, so that traversing the tree ends as soon as possible for most of the RT's.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. 
We currently support matching one column at a time, i.e. we allow only one-to-one matching sequence. This way we can process about 9000 RTs/sec (there is some database writing involved), which is sufficient. So a total time of 4hrs should be good enough for 150 million RTs provided that the matching algorithm can keep up pumping matched records as fast as the db engine writes data to a temp table.